# MSBuild fails for .NET Core SDK Version 2.2.202

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After downloading and installing Visual Studio 2019 RC, I cannot run msbuild, and get the following error:

**"Version 2.2.202 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.0.0 of MSBuild.
The current available version of MSBuild is 15.6.82.30579. 
Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available."**

I cannot find MSBuild version 16. The only version I find is this one here: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0"

Comment: Have you tried updating your Visual Studio?

Comment: Yep, when I updated it now, it worked. Thanks @Matthiee

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updating `Visual Studio` to the minimum supported version or above should fix this problem.

Some `.NET Core` versions also include fixes in `MSBuild`. They are distributed together with `Visual Studio`.

They put the minimum supported versions in the release notes of `.NET Core`.

For example:  [Announcing .NET Core 2.2 | .NET Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-2-2/)

Comment: Do Visual Studio versions related directly to Microsoft.Build versions?

Comment: @Marie yes, for example see [MSBuild 16.3.2 shipped with Visual Studio 2019 16.3.6](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/releases/tag/v16.3.2.50909)

Answer (score 13):

.NET Core SDK versions `2.2.2XX` and `2.1.6XX` are intended to be used with Visual Studio 2019 and MSBuild `16.x`.

.NET Core SDK versions for Visual Studio 2017 are `2.2.1XX` and `2.1.5XX`.

See this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2555) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for this info. I was uninstalling "old" SDKs, and I found that I could no longer build a solution at work that still needed MSBuild 15.x. Having those version number ranges was a huge timesaver!

Answer (score 5):

For people coming here because they have the in Azure DevOps Pipelines - here some pointers for that.

If you have a **private agent pool** configured (e.g. private build machine), you might want to update your machine to support a more recent MSBuild version. See other answers.

If you don't have configured a build agent and use a default agent pool provided by Azure DevOps itself (e.g. "Hosted" or VS2019), see if there is a newer Hosted one that supports your configuration. See screenshot below where to look.

[image: Select an Agent pool in the "Run pipeline" step]

Comment: In my case: changing the agent specification value from "windows-2019" to "windows-latest" fixed things

Answer (score 4):

I had the following issue as I am running 2019 (for 2.1 project) and 2022 (7.0 projects) in parallel in my development computer.

the project file cannot be opened. version 7.0.304 of the .net sdk requires at least version 17.4.0 of msbuild. the current available version of msbuild is 16.11.2.50704. change the .net sdk specified in global.json to an older version that requires the msbuild version currently available.

I assumed 2.1 is installed through MSVS 2019. But I saw above error.

I installed dotnet 2.1 from following link. I reopened the solution all the projects which were unable to load with above error, all of them loaded properly.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-2.1.818-windows-x64-installer

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is still coming across this issue.  I found another way, to get around this without upgrading to VS 2019 or rolling back SDK 3.1.  My experience is in TFS 2017 (on-prem).  I'm the build engineer, not a developer.
I had an SDK 2.2 app that was failing after the install of 3.1.
Initially, it was causing the NuGet steps to fail.  Research led to me asking the developers to add a global.json file having it point to 2.2.  This fixed the NuGet errors. 
Then MSBuild step was failing with similar to OPs message.  Couldn't figure out why 3.1 was taking presedence over 2.2 when it was listed in global.json.  So I started digging around in the SDK in stall folders (typically located in C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk).  I came across a file named **minimumMSBuildVersion**  In the SDK\3.1.101 folder that file has version 16.3.0 of MSBuild listed.  I then went to the SDK 2.2 folder and checked it there.  It has version 15.3.0 which my build server has.  I simply changed the version to this in the 3.1 folder and my build succeeded.  I hope this helps anyone that may still be experiencing build issues when .Net Core SDK versions are updated on their TFS Build Servers.

Comment: Changing random required versions without knowing what they are used for or what the down stream effects are is a terrible idea. That may come back to bite you

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with our on-prem build server we use with GitHub Actions.

The solution was to run Visual Studio Installer and update Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 and 2019.

I realize this solution is very similiar to those above, but I wanted to speak to the situations where Visual Studio is *not* installed, but Build Tools are.

Answer (score 0):

I have closed my all visual studio professtional 2019 instances. My project is using `netcoreapp3.1` as TargetFramework.

1. Installed .Net Framework 3.1 using this link https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-3.1.32-windows-x64-installer
2. rename of "minimumMSBuildVersion" file, in "c:\program files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306 to "___minimumMSBuildVersion".
3. Restart Visual Studio IDE as admin and the problem is solved.