# What version of .NET Core can I develop in using MSBuild tools ver. 15.6?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, teamcity, teamcity-10

I am limited in terms of the version of build tools available to Teamcity (MSBuild 15.6.82.30579) though local development in VS 2017 is at to 15.9.

What version of .NET Core can we safely develop in given MSBuild 15.6 on our deployment agent? I've been looking through:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0

It looks like we may be limited to .NET Core 2.0 - is this accurate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420731/msbuild-fails-for-net-core-sdk-version-2-2-202  Post your own answer there when you find out that earlier versions don't work either.

Comment: It is worth to migrate to newer tools. .NET Core 2.0 is end of life, .NET Core 2.2 the same. You have two options - .NET Core 2.1 which is a LTS (end of life on 2021-08-21) and .NET Core 3.1 which is also LTS with end of life after 2022-12-03.

Comment: @HansPassant - I've seen that question, it refers entirely to later versions than I've referenced.

Comment: Hi @Hostel, assume for now that I cannot upgrade. Can I build .NET Core 2.1 apps with MSBuild 15.6?

Comment: @MissCellaneous if MSBuild is connected with version of Visual Studio then non of MSBuild 15 will support .NET Core grater than 2.0. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs

Comment: Thanks for this @Hostel, that helps confirm my thinking. I'm going to attempt to get upgraded to a point, but I wanted to understand where I stood if I'm unable to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the answer is indeed 2.0, based on comments and the docs I linked earlier.

However, I have been able to upgrade to MSBuild tools 15.9 for now, enabling .net core 2.2 or 2.1 development.

Note: We are developing in 2.1, since it is on Long Term Support.

Comment: You should develop using .net core 2.1. Version 2.2 is no longer supported.

Comment: Hi @Hostel yes, thank you - think the penny just dropped with that this morning :/ (I know you had mentioned that was LTS before)