# Azure DevOps build fails after upgrading app to from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: azure, azure-devops, msbuild, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a build which works fine locally (VSCode, .NET Core 3.1.101) but fails with the following message when run in an Azure DevOps Pipeline.

My pipeline is stripped down to the most basic:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

And that results in this error message:

> Version 3.1.101 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.3.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 15.9.21.664. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.

I can't find a way to change the version of MSBuild that the pipeline runs and changing to an older version of .NET Core surely defeats the purpose of upgrading?

Is there any way to build a.NET Core 3.1 solution on Azure DevOps?

Comment: can you post how does your task looks like

Comment: Good point.  I've added the YAML for the build steps to question.

Comment: The windows-2019 image with 16.4 but you are referring to 15.9. version, so it seems related to your project, would you please share a sample to us to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anywhere you are having the dotnet build task, you need to have the dotnetbuild task with the version configured,

```
steps:

    - task: UseDotNet@2 
      displayName: ".NET Core 3.1.x"
      inputs:
        version: '3.1.x'
        packageType: sdk
    - script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
      displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Refer this [article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SettingUpAzureDevOpsCICDForANETCore31WebAppHostedInAzureAppServiceForLinux.aspx).

Comment: Noop, it still not working `Version 3.0.102 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.3.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 15.9.21.664. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.`

Comment: I do not think its an azure devops related one, i doubt something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55420731/msbuild-fails-for-net-core-sdk-version-2-2-202

Comment: I think I got it! https://stackoverflow.com/a/58168141/1958882 Well it built with some warnings but it seems to be working.

Comment: I tried that - removed the NuGet commands and replaced with dotnet restore.  That bit works but now the dotnet build gives and error: The TargetFramework value 'netcoreapp3.1' was not recognized. It may be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly

Comment: I stripped the pipeline definition to only include the bit up to where it fails.  The orignal had the dotnet build bits, but it isn't getting that far.

Comment: @sajeetharan it works fine when I build it using Visual Studio or VSCode or from the command line.  It only fails on Azure DevOps.

Comment: Has this been solved. I cannot get this to work in Azure either

Comment: @CodeMan03 Which agent are you using? Ubuntu 18.04 is working for me...

Comment: Using visual studio 2019

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to restore nuget packages, compile nad run unit tests using this YAML

```yaml
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  rootDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore nuget packages
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    workingDirectory: $(rootDirectory)

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    projects: '$(rootDirectory)/*.sln'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

# You just added coverlet.collector to use 'XPlat Code Coverage'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- RunConfiguration.DisableAppDomain=true'
    workingDirectory: $(rootDirectory)
```

I assumed that you solution file is in the root directory. If you use global json please set sdk version to `3.1.201` otherwise another steo may be required.

global.json

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.201",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```